# Append the result of an iteration into divs created in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a game for a practice project and have run into an issue while trying to figure out how to append the results of an iterated array into divs created by a for loop. The divs with the appended array data will then be pushed to the DOM.

The focus of this question is the loop at the bottom of this stack. I've included the rest of the JS code (and notes) as reference.

It correctly iterates my array (var splitWordArray) and correctly creates a number of divs equal to that iteration.

Its at that point that I'm just unsure of the code to push the individual letters of splitWordArray into those divs.

I'm assuming appendChild() would be the way to do it but I'd love to get the community's input as I work on the problem.

The expected result for the word `cat` would be:

```
<div>
    <div>c</div><div>a</div><div>t</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

```
//Hangman PSEUDOCODE
//declare words array
var hangManWords = ['potato', 'mobile', 'lego', 'jacket',
`enter code here`'apple', 'cat', 'throne', 'street',];


//Game start - Display in HTML, "Press any key to get started"
$("#startButton").on("click", function() {
  console.log("START BUTTON CLICKED")
  document.onkeyup = gameStart();
});



    //User presses any key to start.
    var gameStart = function startGame() {

  //Random word is pulled from hangManWords array.
  var getRandomWord = hangManWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
  hangManWords.length)];
  console.log("Your word is " + getRandomWord);

  //word choice is counted
  var wordLength = getRandomWord.length;
  console.log("There are " + wordLength + " letters in the word 
  chosen");

  //word choice is split into its seperate letters and stored in an 
  //array called splitWordArray.
  var splitWordArray = getRandomWord.split("");
  console.log("The word is now split thusly " + splitWordArray);

  //Computer determines number of guesses.
  var guessNumber = (wordLength + 6);
  console.log("You have " + guessNumber + " guesses to win");;

  //Display instructions as alert();
   console.log("Alert = Choose letters in order to guess the word! 
   You have "  + guessNumber + " guesses");

  //create divs, iterate splitWordArray out and append splitWordArray 
  //into them.

  var hangDiv = document.createElement("div")

  for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){
  console.log(hangDiv);
  console.log(splitWordArray[i]);
  console.log(hangDiv.appendChild(splitWordArray));
  };

  };// gameStart function endtag
```

Comment: `.appendChild` expects an HTML Element as arg

Comment: you could do `innerHTML +=`

Comment: What is the expected result/output? Should the letters be wrapped in `<div>`s, `<span>`s, ... ?

Comment: @Rajesh thats true when appending to the DOM but I'm trying to append splitWordArray into hangDiv post iteration.

Comment: @Andreas yes thats what I'm hoping to achieve. So for instance if the word is "cat" it ends up as <div>c</div>    <div>a</div>       <div>t</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
var str = "hello";

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  var hangDiv = document.createElement("div");
    hangDiv.innerHTML = str[i];
    document.body.appendChild(hangDiv);
  };
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wwsetu9t/)

Comment: That's not the result the TO asks for and is, when fixed, essentially the same code as the one from Rajesh

Comment: @Andreas in the comments, OP says he wants each character to be encapsulated by a `div` and this is what my code does. If you are insinuating that I copied Rajesh then you are wrong lol I just happened to post it a few seconds after him

Comment: @JosanIracheta No one is accusing anyone. All Andreas meant was, its duplicate/redundant content.

Comment: @Rajesh you literally posted your answer a few seconds before me. I didn't even see it until I posted it lol

Comment: @JosanIracheta Lets not debate over it. Also it was 300+ seconds before :-p. So, I'd request you to add something that my answer does not addresses, so we both contribute something. Have a good day :-)

Answer (score 0):

As commented before,

> .appendChild expects a Node/html element.

You will have to create new elements in loop and append them to your div.

**Sample:**

```js
for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
  console.log(hangDiv);
  console.log(splitWordArray[i]);
  var span = document.createElement('span')
  span.innerHTML = splitWordArray[i]
  console.log(hangDiv.appendChild(span));
};
```

You can debug the code using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/mn9vus9p/) or using below snippet:

```js
//Hangman PSEUDOCODE
//declare words array
var hangManWords = ['potato', 'mobile', 'lego', 'jacket',
  'apple', 'cat', 'throne', 'street',
];

//Game start - Display in HTML, "Press any key to get started"
$("#startButton").on("click", function() {
  console.log("START BUTTON CLICKED")
  document.onkeyup = gameStart();
});

//User presses any key to start.
var gameStart = function startGame() {

  //Random word is pulled from hangManWords array.
  var getRandomWord = hangManWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * hangManWords.length)];
  console.log("Your word is " + getRandomWord);

  //word choice is counted
  var wordLength = getRandomWord.length;
  console.log("There are " + wordLength + " letters in the word chosen ");

  //word choice is split into its seperate letters and stored in an 
  //array called splitWordArray.
  var splitWordArray = getRandomWord.split("");
  console.log("The word is now split thusly " + splitWordArray);

  //Computer determines number of guesses.
  var guessNumber = (wordLength + 6);
  console.log("You have " + guessNumber + " guesses to win");;

  //Display instructions as alert();
  console.log("Alert = Choose letters in order to guess the word! You have " + guessNumber + "guesses ");

  //create divs, iterate splitWordArray out and append splitWordArray 
  //into them.

  var hangDiv = document.createElement("div")

  for (i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    console.log(hangDiv);
    console.log(splitWordArray[i]);
    var span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerHTML = splitWordArray[i]
    console.log(hangDiv.appendChild(span));
  };
  document.querySelector('.content').appendChild(hangDiv)
}; // gameStart function endtag
```

```css
span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="startButton">Start</button>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Rajesh. Will give that a shot!